# Using VBA to find a specific word and copying the values next to it into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and  am trying to create a macro. I want to look for the word “Cash and Cash Equivalents” in column B of the EVE_Workbook (Source) then copy the 7 values (cells) to the right of it into column D of Macro_Results (destination). The reason I need a macro is because I’m would have to replicate this for multiple variables across multiple spreadsheets and the cells don't all match up.
I have been looking all over online but haven’t found anything substantial yet. Am I on the right track? The Range.Offset is also tripping me up so any advice on what I am doing wrong there would be awesome. Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
With Sheets("EVE_Workbook")
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

With .Range("B:B")
    Criteria1 = "Cash and Cash Equivalents"
Range.Offset(0, 1).Offset(0, 7).Copy
Sheets("Macro_Results").Cell("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Show what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty weak question, but here's an easy way to get started learning a little. It loops through your range looking at the value of each cell and then puts something in column D. If you specify your question or try some code on your own, you might get more help.

```
Sub tryHarder()

    Dim aCell As Range, WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet '

    With WS

    For Each aCell In Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange).Cells
        'this creates a loop of used cells in column b to check.

        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, "Cash and Cash Equivalants", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            'this inserts a value of boom 2 columns to the right of the found cell
            aCell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Boom"

        End If

    Next aCell

End With
End Sub
```

If you wanted to use the [FIND Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), that works also, but it gets a little complex as you Find Again. You can look that up on your own. The above approach is slower and not effecient in that it writes to the template too frequently, but hopefully, you can get the idea.

Comment: This is what I had so far but it keeps copying from the macro results tab?

Comment: Dim LastRow As Long
    With Sheets("EVE_Workbook")
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With .Range("B:B")
             Criteria1 = "Cash and Cash Equivalents"
             Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7)).Copy
             Sheets("Macro_Results").Range("D2:D8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub

Comment: Nobody can read that. Paste it into your question as something you've tried, and make sure it's formatted as mine is using the code block. You can preview what you're doing as you type.

Comment: Sorry if the first post seemed vague. I actually have been fiddling around for a few hours with it but to know avail.

Comment: @Mike_2000 I know it's hard when you're first getting started. If you paste your code in a legible format so we can at least say the proper breaks and stuff, you'll get some help. If you can't do there, post on Pastebin.com and just include the link someone will fix it for you.